# How to calculate father organ statistics using SQL

Tags: sql, db2

Recently I am working on querying data to form reports for a company, new to SQL.

I have the raw data of the child organ, meanwhile , I also need to calculate the total amount of it's parent organ.

I have used full outer join to put all the organs together in one table, adding one column "parent_organ" to indicate their relations, shown in picture:

[image]

I have some times to use below SQL query, but failed, can anyone help? Thanks.

```
 SELECT ORGAN,
    SUM(CASE WHEN parent_organ LIKE '%'||ORGAN||'%' THEN 
            sales 
        ELSE 0 END) AS sales_sum  
 FROM table GROUP BY organ
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Do you really have the parent organs stored as a comma separated list in your table? That is a **really** bad design. You should [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement to your question. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: we are using DB2 10.5. It's a legacy table, agree with you on its bad design .I have simplified my question. Indeed, the table has five level organs, that is   ,A∈B∈C∈D∈E, Where only A , the lowest level has the real business data， all parents' (B,C,D,E) statistics should be calculated by adding them up. There are also lots of organs like A and B,C,D,E. I know this prob can be solved by using SP and creating a new Table to hold the data. but want to a solve this using SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Postgres I assume, going by the `||` concatenation? From the full outer join row set:

```
SELECT organ, sales FROM test WHERE parent IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT a.organ, sum(b.sales)
FROM test a
JOIN test b ON b.parent LIKE '%'||a.organ||'%'
GROUP BY a.organ;
```

This is obviously not great since it renders your original join redundant: it's running two queries and simply pushing the results together. You'd be better off without the full outer join and editing each query to get the data from the original source.

I don't think there's a better way with the setup you've presented though. If the parent-child relationship is a proper foreign key you might get somewhere with [`GROUPING SETS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) from the original tables, but that's not going to work with the string matching you're doing.

Comment: The `||` is not Postgres specific. It's the string concatenation operator defined in the SQL standard.